# remove particular characters from a variable using bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

I want to parse a **variable** (in my case it's development kit version) to make it dot(`.`) free. If `version='2.3.3'`, desired output is `233`.

I tried as below, but it requires `.` to be replaced with another character giving me `2_3_3`. It would have been fine if `tr . ''` would have worked.

```
  1 VERSION='2.3.3' 
  2 echo "2.3.3" | tr . _
```

Comment: No, it doesn't require: `echo "2.3.3" | tr -d .`.

Comment: @manatwork Great, that works. You can post it as answer. Thanks

Comment: Lot of good answers. But if I can second-guess the objective, be warned about 2.11.3 and 2.1.13... ;-) Consider adding padding zeroes to numbers.

Comment: @Rmano You mean something like `VERSION='2.30.3100'`? No matter what just `.`'s are removed with all of the answers here.

Comment: @PrayagUpd --- I simply meant that if you will use the number after the conversion for comparisons (as to say if "is this version newer or the same") you should take care of cases like 2.11.3 and 2.1.13 --- they seems the same after dot removal, but clearly 2.11.3 is newer. Also, 2.11.3 is newer than 2.1.14, but comparing 2113 and 2114 will lead to the wrong answer. I remember a bug somewhere for this...

Comment: @Rmano Got you. But my purpose is to identify the version in my project and get the development kit of that version located somewhere in filesystem. You can go through [my bash file](https://github.com/iPrayag/gccount/blob/master/run-app.sh#L4). Thx anyway for for warn :)

Comment: @PrayagUpd so how do you differentiate the directories for version 2.11.3 and 2.1.13? Or are you sure you have one-digit subversion ever?

Comment: @Rmano Looking over kit's history, it has [1-digit sub- version so far](http://grails.org/download).

Answer (score 252, accepted):

There is no need to execute an external program. `bash`'s [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) can handle it (also available in `ksh93` (where it comes from), `zsh` and recent versions of `mksh`, `yash` and busybox `sh` (at least)):

```
$ VERSION='2.3.3'
$ echo "${VERSION//.}"
233
```

(In those shells' manuals you can generally find this in the *parameter expansion* section.)

Comment: For further detail, the syntax of the above answer is `${string//substring/replacement}`, where apparently the lack of the final forward slash and replacement string are interpreted as *delete*. See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: Right, `man bash` says it clearly in the [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) section: “`${parameter/pattern/string}` (…) If _string_ is null, matches of _pattern_ are deleted and the `/` following _pattern_ may be omitted.”

Comment: My issue was that the version number came like this  `"1.0.0"` and I wanted just the number so follow what @manatwork suggested I changed in: `"${VERSIONNUM//'"'}"` however I insert even `' ' `because otherwise it wouldn't recognise the `""` like string to take off.

Comment: @Alexiscanny, you mean literal `"` are present in the value? I'm afraid this counts as new question, but try to just escape the doublequote: `"${VERSIONNUM//\"}"` http://pastebin.com/3ECDtkwH

Comment: Superb!! works on `-ash` too!

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr, that would be busybox' `ash` (when built with ASH_BASH_COMPAT )even though that's a ksh feature, not bash)) . The original `ash` didn't have it and I'm not aware of any other `ash` derivative (only tried `dash` and FreeBSD `sh` though) that has it.

Comment: Not wanting to be a OT or a killjoy, but following the intention of the above, it would be far better to ensure that the digits are separated.  For instance, compare nominal versions with 2.11.1  and 2.1.12 .  The above method will fail dramatically. In fact so would 3.0 vs 2.1.6

Comment: So, again if wanting to get versions - especially for comparison, it would be far better to use "sort -V"

Answer (score 137):

By chronological order:

#### tr/sed

```
echo "$VERSION" | tr -d .
echo "$VERSION" | sed 's/\.//g'
```

#### csh/tcsh

```
echo $VERSION:as/.//
```

#### POSIX shells:

```
set -f
IFS=.
set -- $VERSION
IFS=
echo "$*"
```

#### ksh93/zsh/mksh/bash/yash (and busybox `ash` when built with `ASH_BASH_COMPAT`)

```
echo "${VERSION//.}"
```

#### zsh

```
echo $VERSION:gs/./
```

Comment: tr -d deleted even single char from the set. For Ex i want to delete DCC_ from "DCC_VersionD", It deletes DCC and D. Expected output : VersionD. Actual Output : Version. sed worked like a charm. :) thanks for the post.

Answer (score 32):

In addition to the successful answers already exists. Same thing can be achieved with `tr`, with the `--delete` option.

```
echo "2.3.3" | tr --delete .
echo "2.3.3" | tr -d .       # for MacOS
```

Which will output: `233`

Comment: on macos the `--delete` flag is not recognised, but you can use `-d` instead

Answer (score 10):

You should try with `sed` instead

```
sed 's/\.//g'
```

Comment: A POSIX compliant one liner, nice.

Answer (score 7):

```
echo "$VERSION" | tr -cd [:digit:]
```

That would return only digits, no matter what other characters are present

Comment: Only if there's no file called `:`, `d`, `i`, `g` or `t` in the current directory and you're using a shell that doesn't complain upon non-matching globs and leaves them asis (most Bourne-like ones and rc-like ones) or a shell that doesn't support `[...]` globs (like `fish`).

Answer (score 5):

#### Perl

```
$ VERSION='2.3.3'                                     
$ perl -pe 's/\.//g' <<< "$VERSION"           
233
```

#### Python

```
$ VERSION='2.3.3'                                     
$ python -c 'import sys;print sys.argv[1].replace(".","")' "$VERSION"
233
```

If `$VERSION` only contains digits and dots, we can do something even shorter:

```
$ python -c 'print "'$VERSION'".replace(".","")'
233
```

(beware it's a code injection vulnerability though if `$VERSION` may contain any character).

#### AWK

```
$ VERSION='2.3.3'
$ awk 'BEGIN{gsub(/\./,"",ARGV[1]);print ARGV[1]}' "$VERSION"
233
```

Or this:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\./,"")}1' <<< "$VERSION"
233
```